# Positive semidefinite ordering of matrices after small perturbations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, nuclear-norm

We use the notation $A\leq B$ to denote that $B-A$ is positive semidefinite. The notation $|\cdot |_1$ denotes the nuclear norm i.e. $|X|_1 = \operatorname{Tr}\sqrt{X^*X}$, where $X^*$ is the transpose conjugate of $X$.

Let $\rho$ and $\sigma$ be positive semidefinite matrices such that $\rho \leq \sigma$. Consider some positive semidefinite matrix $\omega$ which is close to $\sigma$ in nuclear norm i.e. $|\omega - \sigma|_1 \leq \varepsilon$. Does there always exist a positive semidefinite matrix $\tau$ such that

$$|\tau - \rho|_1 \leq \varepsilon \quad \text{and} \quad \tau \leq \omega$$

Note that the problem is quite easy if $\tau$ is not required to be positive semidefinite.

Comment: @BenGrossmann that's a good point. I think $2\varepsilon$ or similar would still be fine.

Comment: I suspect that it doesn't matter much; I had gotten confused between $\rho$ and $\sigma$ somewhere when I commented

Comment: You could probably get some insight here using the case in which $\rho$ has rank $1$. If we write $\rho = \alpha xx^*$ for some $\alpha \geq 0$, we find that $\rho \leq \sigma$ holds if and only if the matrix 
$$
\pmatrix{\rho & x\\ x^*  & \alpha^{-1}}
$$
is positive semidefinite, which holds if and only if we have $\alpha \leq [x^* \rho^+ x]^{-1}$, where $\rho^+$ denotes the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $\rho$; see [this post for details](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3630803/81360).

Comment: That should be a $\sigma$ intead of a $\rho$ after the "if and only if"

Comment: Note also that for a unit vector $x$ and operator $\sigma$, there exists an $\alpha > 0$ for which $\alpha xx^* \leq \rho$ iff $\sigma x \neq 0$. Arguably, for a sufficiently small $\epsilon$, $\omega x$ is necessarily non-zero, which means that we can find a suitable $\tau$ by decreasing $\alpha$. Or, if there is an $\omega$ within $\varepsilon$ of $\sigma$ for which $\omega x = 0$, then perhaps this implies that $\alpha \leq \varepsilon$ or something like that

Comment: Thank you for the comments - I will digest your linked answer and see how to use it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Here is a counterexample. Let $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ be sufficiently small and
\begin{aligned}
A&=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&1},
\ B=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1},\\
X&=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&1-\epsilon}.
\end{aligned}
Then $A\ge B\ge0,\,X\ge0$ and $|X-A|_1=\epsilon$. However, if $X\ge Y\ge0$, we must have
$$
1-\epsilon=x_{22}\ge y_{22}\ge0.\tag{1}
$$
It follows that
$$
|Y-B|_1\ge\sigma_1(Y-B)\ge|e_2^\ast(Y-B)e_2|=|y_{22}-b_{22}|=|y_{22}-1|\ge\epsilon.\tag{2}
$$
So, if $|Y-B|_1\le\epsilon$, ties must occur in all three inequalities in $(2)$. The tie in the first inequality implies that the rank of $Y-B$ is at most one. The tie in the second inequality implies that $e_2$ is both a left and a right singular vector corresponding to the largest singular value of $Y-B$. Hence $Y-B=(y_{22}-b_{22})e_2e_2^T$, i.e.
$$
Y=\pmatrix{b_{11}&b_{12}\\ b_{21}&y_{22}}=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&y_{22}}
$$
But the tie in the third inequality in $(2)$ also implies that $|y_{22}-1|=\epsilon$. By $(1)$, this means $y_{22}=1-\epsilon$. Hence $Y$ is not PSD, which is a contradiction.